# Get Key in Dictionary<string, List<viewModel>>

Tags: c#

I have object like this:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
     public int ReportNumber { get; set; }
     public int EmployerID{ get; set; }
     public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

Currently I am getting the all the values like this:

```
  Dictionary<string, List<TestViewModel>> dataWithRules = Dictionary<string, List<TestViewModel>>();
```

The values in the dictionary are like this:

```
+ Red    100
+ Orange 80
+ Pink   50

In Detail level:
- Red 100
  100001 3456  Test
  100002 5896  Test2
  100003 78596 Test3
- Orange  80
  100004 8896 Test4
  100005 5632 Test4
```

Question: I am inserting these values into a staging table by flattening the table using this statement: `dataWithRules.SelectMany(s => s.Value).Take(200);`

When I say `Take(200)`, it has Key values from "Red, Orange, Pink"and I want to insert these values for a relating row in the staging table and having difficulty. Please help.

Comment: how Take(200) is related with "Red, Orange, Pink"?

Comment: Red, Orange and Pink are the Key values. Each Key has a list of TestViewModel. While saving into a table I am using Take(200) which includes values from Red, Orange and Pink. I need to insert Red for 100 rows and Orange for 80 rows and Pink for 20 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
var results = dataWithRules.SelectMany(
    s => s.Value.Select(v => new { Key = s.Key, Value = v })).Take(200);
```

or maybe

```
var results = dataWithRules.SelectMany(
    s => s.Value.Select(v => new 
        { 
            Color = s.Key, 
            ReportNumber = v.ReportNumber,
            EmployerID = v.EmployerID,
            Description = v.Description 
        }))
    .Take(200);
```

Now the results will include the the color key and the `TestViewModel` values.  If you need to pass this around you can use `Tuple` or a custom class instead of an anonymous class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How do I get the Key only?

Comment: @DeepakVodethela I'm not sure I follow what you mean?  `dataWithRules.Keys` will give you all the keys.  Do you mean you only want values for a specific key?

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It helped me and works perfectly.